# Dev(Sec)Ops - Analysis and testing frameworks for developers

Tags: devops

I work in a development team and we are looking at moving into DevOps with a "shift left" approach with regards to security to bring us inline with DevSecOps

What analysis and testing frameworks are available? How best approach the user stories we're coming to come across?

I have lots of bookmarked resources to read through but was hoping for a nudge in the right direction with the tools mentioned